# Wrong image on the newsfeed - correct meta tags?

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

When I publish an link to my facebook page using a http post to:

`https://graph.facebook.com/MYID/feed`

I get the wrong image on the timeline. The title and description is correct. When I check the URL in the object debugger, everything seems fine.

For example, the following url gives me this problem:
http://www.weekmenu.nl/hollands/knapperige_slastamppot_met_gebakken_feta/

As you can see on this screenshot, the wrong image is shown in the timeline:
`http://www.weekmenu.nl/wrong.png`

(I'm sorry, i'm not allowed to post images or more than 2 links.. stupid stackoverflow)

It should be:
http://www.weekmenu.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/e10a13fa3a3d7f660abf9aabe9651078.jpg

Are the meta tags correct on my page?

This is the PHP code I use to post the recipe to my facebook page:

```
$params = array('access_token'=>get_option('weekmenu_social_fb_access_token'), 'message'=>$message_facebook, 'link'=>$link);
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".get_option('weekmenu_social_fb_page_id')."/feed";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => $url,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
   CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
));
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Where lies the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook caches its results the first time a page is scraped - to force that to refresh, you need to use their [URL Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

If you put your page's address into that tool, the correct information will be displayed the next time the link is posted to facebook.

Comment: Well, this is not an answer oto my question. As I indicated the 'URL Linter', which is actually called the Object Debugger, shows the right metadata.

Comment: You're right, I misread your question - my apologies. Unfortunately I can't see anything wrong with your code - it does look to be correct. It's worth mentioning that even running the linter (or Object Debugger as they now call it) won't update anything that's been posted to facebook in the past, only new posts. If it's still happening every time the link is posted, perhaps try addressing some of the warnings the debugger's spitting out and see if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `og:image` meta tag. If you have not any put one with correct image url.

Comment: If you followed my example link, you could see that the og:image tag is correct.